# AWS Serverless Error for Provider variables - Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using Serverless framework.

I have created Cognito user pool in one stack and importing it into second stack.

When I assign the value of the Cognito User pool ID created in the first stack, to the environment variable it works.

But when I try to use it while creating a ARN for Cognito Authorizer, it doesn't work.
I get an error - **Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable**

Here is the snippet of my serverless.yml file.

```
service: myservice

plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

  cognitoUserPoolId :
    Fn::ImportValue: cloudformation-resources-${self:provider.stage}-CognitoUserPool
  cognitoAppClientId :
    Fn::ImportValue: cloudformation-resources-${self:provider.stage}-CognitoUserPoolClient


custom:

  environment:

    COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID : ${self:provider.cognitoUserPoolId}
    COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID: ${self:provider.cognitoAppClientId}

functions:
  myfunction:
    handler: bin/handlers/myfunction
    package:
     exclude:
        - "**/**"
     include:
       - ./bin/handlers/myfunction
    events:         

      - http:
            path: mypath
            method: put
            authorizer:
               name: cognitoapiauthorizer
               arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:userpool/${self:provider.cognitoUserPoolId}
            cors: true
```

Any issues related to indentation or the way it is being used in another variable like ARN?

Comment: I haven't spent much time on it, but from the first look, it seems to be the "arn" issue. 

arn: !Sub "arn:aws:cognito-idp:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:userpool/${self:provider.cognitoUserPoolId}"

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to resolve the error `Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable`. In my experience, this means that the variable is empty. What happens if you hardcode the `cognitoUserPoolId` at the end of the ARN? Is the error resolved? I suspect it would be. Moving forward from there, you should take a closer look at how you declare that variable. Your usage of `Fn::ImportValue` may not working as intended.

Also, I would definitely run your YAML through a validator. There are too many extra blank lines, and extra spaces before the colons e.g. `COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID : ${self:provider.cognitoUserPoolId}`. These may be causing problems. Keep your YAML formatting tidy.

Comment: Late comment, but want to leave it for visibility: Imports from another stack outputs are sort of `special` strings: you can use them independently as variables, but when it comes to ARNs - they will break the compilation of the template